# Migrate big SQL tables to SQL azure

Tags: sql, database, azure, azure-sql-database

We want to move our database to SQL azure. I'm using SQLAzureMW tool v3.8 to do this.

In our SQL database there are 2 tables with some varbinary data and SQLAzureMW having troubles with copying these (large) tables. Whats the best way to get these data in SQL azure.

We tried scripting these tables but that didn't work... Maybe we need to script them in smaller pieces?

Or are there some simplier solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would created smaller batches and insert them per batch in Azure.  This gives you the opportunity to insert them in parallel too.

Comment: Depending on how you do it, you can also tweak the batch size if you still run into problems.

Comment: Have you got any examples of how to create these batches?

Comment: I found some information about BCP or bulk insert is this a good way? To first convert your data to an XML-file and than insert it with BCP in AZURE?